# Secure password reset on Laravel 5.4 using the API

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

How can I reset password using the REST API for `laravel5.4`? The user must receive an email to reset the password:

I followed this tutorial:

http://blog.nasrulhazim.com/2017/01/reset-your-password-from-api/

but is not secure, anybody can reset the my password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Directly `Auth::routes()` into your Api it working as you wish

For Reset Password use this Url `baseurl()+password.email` and Give parameter `email` in post method

it's Working..

Comment: It is unclear answer, please give more description !!